# integrate LinkedIn login in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to integrate the script below in a React component (in `componentDidMount`) but I get an error at IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData); IN is not recognizet. My main goal is to integrate this script in my React component.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: YOUR_API_KEY_HERE
    authorize: true
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
    }

    // Handle the successful return from the API call
    function onSuccess(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

    // Handle an error response from the API call
    function onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    // Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
    function getProfileData() {
        IN.API.Raw("/people/~").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: i am trying to integrate the script above in a react component (in componentDidMount) but i get an error at IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
IN is not recognizet.
My main goal is to integrate this script in my react component
Thank you in advance

Comment: So how is your code related to react? What you've posted doesn't have any smells of a react component. Please be more descriptive and show what you've already tried.

Comment: Can't put code inside a script tag that has an src. It will be completely ignored

Comment: componentDidMount = () => {
  // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
  function onLinkedInLoad() {
   IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
  }
  
  // Handle the successful return from the API call
  function onSuccess(data) {
   console.log(data);
  }
  
  // Handle an error response from the API call
  function onError(error) {
   console.log(error);
  }
  
  // Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
  function getProfileData() {
   IN.API.Raw("/people/~").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
  }
 }

Comment: an this is my error:
index.js:2178 ./src/components/Login.js
  Line 239:  'IN' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 239:  'IN' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 254:  'IN' is not defined  no-undef